# BackgroundWorker on boolean functions c#

Tags: c#, background, boolean, backgroundworker

I have a boolean function. I have a bw which I wish to use to run this function.
I want to get the return value from the function, is it possible?

Here is a sample code:

```
void Main ()
{
     BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
     backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender1, e1) => testBool();
     bool result = backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync;
}

bool testBool()
{
     return true;
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.  The point of using BackgroundWorker is to run code on another thread.  Which takes its time to calculate a result.  Waiting for that result completely defeats the point of using a worker, and is very likely to cause deadlock as well, you might as well call testBool() directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event to recieve a notification about a fact that the computaion terminated.

Inside that `testBool(..)` you can set global variable, and after inside 
the event handler of `RunWorkerCompleted` read that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **e.Result** like this:
First step: you need to add the event **RunWorkerCompleted**.

```
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BwRunWorkerCompleted;
```

And create the function **BwRunWorkerCompleted**, this will be fired after the thread is complete. For example:

```
private void BwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }

           // 
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                // test if result is true or false <== HERE YOU GO!
                if ((Boolean)e.Result == true)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Form fm = new SFGrilla(ref lr, ref binding);
                    fm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // hide the progress bar when the long running process finishes
                progressBar.Visible = false;

                // enable button
                btnLogin.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
```

Your testbool() should have the right parameters:

```
private void testbool(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs) {
      success = true;
      doWorkEventArgs.Result = success;
}
```

Hope it helps.